# Rails datetime_select can't set default date if using prompts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having some trouble getting datetime_select to work in my form.  I can get it to EITHER Set the default date OR allow prompts, but not both.  What I really want is something like

```
      2011 June 18 hour minute
```

where the default values for the day, month and year popups are set, but the default values for the hour and minute are not.  If I use this code:

```
     <%= f.datetime_select:start_time, 
        :default => Time.now, 
        :prompt => {:hour => "hour", :minute => "minute"} %>
```

I get the values

```
     2006 January 1 hour minute
```

If I don't set the prompts, the default shows just fine.

```
    <%= f.datetime_select:start_time, :default => Time.now  %>
```

yields

```
    2011 June 18 23:53
```

I have also tried setting just the parts of the default that I want

```
    <%= f.datetime_select:start_time, 
     :default =>{:year=>Time.now.year,:month=>Time.now.month,:day=>Time.now.day}, 
  :prompt => {:hour => "hour", :minute => "minute"} %>
```

and it does the same thing as just setting the whole default to Time.now.

Any thoughts?  Is it really not supported to have prompts and a default?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In my knowledge you should probably try something on the following lines :

```
<%= f.datetime_select :start_time, :default => Time.now.strftime('%Y %B %d %H %M') %>
```

Comment: Hmm.  That just gets me "can't convert Symbol into Integer"

Comment: What ? can I see your exact code, or perhaps the stack trace ?

Comment: `<%= form_for @log_entry do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>
   <div class=”field_container”>
   <%= f.label :start_time %> 
   <%= f.datetime_select :start_time,
     :default => Time.now.strftime('%Y %B %d %H %M') %>
   </div>`

Comment: OK that probably wasn't useful.  I put your exact line of code inside my form_for in place of my other call to datetime_select.

Comment: That looks fine, where do you get the "can't convert Symbol into Integer" error ? which line ?

Comment: Just tried it again.  The error is line #7.  The line with the datetime_select.